# Gson parses to LinkedTreeMap when serializing ArrayList of Generic Type

Tags: android, json, arraylist, kotlin, gson

I have this JSON string:

```
[  
   {  
      "k":"number",
      "v":"055 543 8679\n"
   },
   {  
      "k":"hours",
      "v":"8:00AM - 9:00PM"
   }
]
```

And I'm trying to parse it using Gson:

```
    val customFields = Gson().fromJson(food.customFields, ArrayList<CustomField>()::class.java)
```

But somehow when I view it in breakpoint mode, it is parsed as a `LinkedTreeMap`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try this`val customFields = new Gson().fromJson(food.customFields,  CustomField.class);`